# my wordpress posts redirecting to my home page

Tags: wordpress

On my local machine I am running a Wordpress website. When I try to go to my posts, it redirects to my home page.

I want it to show the corresponding page (post's page). Searched in all forums. All in vain.

Do you have any suggestions where to start or how to fix this problem?

Comment: Needed any more informations,please ask.Its urgent,i have to complete the project as soon as possible.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any body here to solve my issue.I am in need of help

Comment: You should not put a clock on questions on stackoverflow. People who answer questions are doing so voluntarily. 1) Put a bounty on your question, 2) add more info. Add everything relevant (permalinks settings, your server configs and .htaccess file, 3) be patient.

Comment: I am bit new to wordpress.my wordpress version is 3.4.1,i am using the default permalink settings

Comment: What are you doing to generate the link to your post's page? Post some code.

Comment: <ul>
                  <?php query_posts('category_name=Key Links&showposts=15&order=DESC'); ?>
   <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   <!-- Do special_cat stuff... -->
                 <li><a href="#">
   <?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
   <?php endwhile;?>
                </ul>

Comment: when,i try to click "view post" in "posts edit page",it redirects to my home page

Comment: Did
 you migrate your WP from other host or other directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just update your orignal post, instead of having us trying to read your code in comments-format.
However, from the code you posted I see two problems.

'category_name=Key Links...' category_name takes a string, which should be the slug-name of your category, "Key Links" can't be your slug since slugs don't allow spaces. So the query is prolly grabbing all posts, disregarding category.

The other problem is where you generate the link

```
<a href="#">,
```

you don't specifiy a url for the link to point to, it should be

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

Comment: Yaah got your point.Sorry i did the mistake in href.i replaced # with the_permalink.it solved my issue.thanks for your patience + reply.